# bootstrap3 form / How to "pull-left" an input-group-addon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form builded with Bootstrap 3 and Ace Admin theme.

In this form, I have form groups with addons but addons are not stucked with input field.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="date" name="dateActivation" id="dateActivation" class="input-control">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-calendar"></i>
      </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to stuck the addon with the input field ?

I don't want to use "form-control text-left" classes because the size of my input field will be changed.

I tried that :

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="input-group pull-left">
    <input type="date" name="dateActivation" id="dateActivation" class="input-control pull-right">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-calendar"></i>
      </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

It do the job for input field & addon but the pull-left doesn't work.

An idea ?

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pNJJN/)

Answer (score 0):

The class for the date input needs to change to `form-control`

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/pNJJN/1/)

Change your HTML to:

```
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="date" name="dateActivation" id="dateActivation" class="form-control"> 
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="ace-icon fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
```

Comment: No, I don't want it. In Ace template it's possible to have a "input-mini" class to have smallest input fields. And if I use "form-control" class, my "input-mini" class is erased ... It's not possible to do the job with a pull-right on the text field and a pull left on the parent div ?

Comment: @ceadreak - can you add the relevant files to your fiddle?

Comment: I cannot add all the thème, but I've added the .input-mini css class